# How to get to know if new file added to a particular folder in google drive

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, flysystem-google-drive

How do I monitor changes to a particular folder in Google drive using  drive Java API?

I am trying the code below, but it give changes for complete drive.

I need the changes for one particular folder

```
StartPageToken response = service.changes().getStartPageToken().execute();
System.out.println("Start token: " + response.getStartPageToken());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [changes/watch](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes/watch), where `resourceId` should be the fileId of the directory to watch - while from the client-side, this is pretty useless - because one has to set parameter `address`, which should be an URL.

Comment: I am using changes only but how to set resource ID here

Comment: see: [Changes](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/Drive.Changes.html) and [Channel.setResourceId()](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/model/Channel.html#setResourceId-java.lang.String-).